# How to append select options after detaching them using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to append select options after detaching them based on the value of the initial select option of a form.

Here's the HTML for my form:

```
<form id="booking-form" action="#" method="post">
<legend class="bold">Bookings</legend>
<div class="input clearfix required">
    <label for="cinema">Cinema</label>
    <select name="cinema" id="cinema">
        <option value></option>
        <option value="maxima">Cinema Maxima</option>
        <option value="rivola">Cinema Rivola</option>
    </select>   
<div class="error">
    <p>Please select a cinema</p>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="input clearfix required">   
    <label for="day">Day</label> 
    <select name="day" id="day">
        <option value></option>
        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
        <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
<div class="error">
    <p>Please select a time</p>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="input clearfix required">   
    <label for="time">Time</label> 
    <select name="time" id="time">
        <option value></option>
        <option value="12">12pm</option>
        <option value="3">3pm</option>
        <option value="4">4pm</option>
        <option value="6">6pm</option>
        <option value="7">7pm</option>
        <option value="9">9pm</option>
    </select>
<div class="error">
    <p>Please select a time</p>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

And here's the jQuery code I've written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

// ***** Begin Booking Form Manipulation ***** //

// If Cinema Maxima is selected, remove Cinema Rivola time options

$('#cinema').change(function() {

    if( $('#cinema').val() == 'maxima') {
            $('#time option[value="12"]').detach();
            $('#time option[value="4"]').detach();
            $('#time option[value="7"]').detach();
        }

// Else, remove Cinema Maxima time options

    else {
            $('#time option[value="3"]').detach();
            $('#time option[value="6"]').detach();
            $('#time option[value="9"]').detach();
        }

});

// If Cinema Maxima is selected but weekend session is not selected, remove 3pm time option

    $('#day').change(function() {

        if( $('#cinema').val() == 'maxima' && $('#day').val() != 'saturday' || 'sunday') {
            $('#time option[value="3"]').detach();
    }   
});



});

// ***** End Booking Form Manipulation ***** //
```

I'm not sure I've I'm approaching this the best way after having spent the last few hours trawling through stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find a solution! Any advice for a beginner would be greatly appreciated!

I've upload my code to jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nness/L9v6ejvt/

Wouldn't you know it - .show() and .hide() seem to work perfectly on my PC when using Chrome! Is anyone else using Chrome on Mac?.. If so, any thoughts as to why it's playing up? The saddest part is had I been using the PC from the get-go this would have saved me the best part of a day! Thanks for all your suggestions guys, all very much appreciated!

Comment: What about just hide or unhide then using `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: That was what I originally tried to do, but didn't have any success (using chrome)... That would be the simplest solution!

Comment: Works for me. I just noticed that what you have in the fiddle - I'll have a look shortly. Note `.detach()` is not a good solution since you need to assign each option to a variable so that you can `.append()` it later.

Comment: Created [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k4z3vyd/) - works fine for cinema but I was not sure what you were trying to acheive with the `$('#day').change(..` function

Comment: Any thoughts on how I could get this to work on Chrome?.. This works a treat on Firefox (haven't test Safari)... But I need this to be able to work on Chrome, which it doesn't for some reason! To answer your question, there's a 3pm session only running on Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Have at look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smpmwr4w/). It was your logic for the day that was wrong - I'm running chrome at its works fine if I understand you corectly (I'm assuming its 3pm session only running on Saturday and Sunday and only for maxima)

Comment: Yeah, your assumption is correct mate! Weird... I can't get any of these fiddles working on my local machine running the latest version of Chrome! Will try having a play around on my PC! Thanks for all the responses mate, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom HTML attributes and then use jQuery
`<option value="maxima" exceptitems="12,9">Cinema Maxima</option>`

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cinema').on('change', function(ev) {
        $('#time option').show();
        var opt=$("option:selected", this);
        var exceptItems=opt.attr('exceptitems');
        if(exceptItems)
        {
            var items=exceptItems.split(",");
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                $('#time option[value="'+items[i]+'"]').hide();
            }           
        }
    });  
});
```

### [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/0nd53L7k/)

> **Update 1:** 
>   I have nice solution

`<option value="maxima" data-command="$('#time option[value=12]').hide()">Cinema Maxima</option>`

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cinema').on('change', function(ev) {                
        var opt=$("option:selected", this);
        var strCommand=opt.data("command");
        eval(strCommand);
    });  
});
```

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/znqypch9/1/)

> **Update 2:** For easy management

```
$.fn.extend({
    executeCommand: function() {
        return this.on('change', function(ev) {
            var opt=$("option:selected", this);
            var strCommand=opt.data("command");
            eval(strCommand);
        });  
    }
});
$('#cinema').executeCommand();
```

### [DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/znqypch9/2/)

Comment: And what about other conditions for the selected day? This solution would be too difficult to manage.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to use an html5 `data-` attribute than an invalid custom attribute.

Comment: Ok see my ``Update 1``.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the corresponding classes for the select as follows:

```
<select name="time" id="time">
        <option value></option>
        <option value="12" class="rivola">12pm</option>
        <option value="3" class="maxima">3pm</option>
        <option value="4" class="rivola">4pm</option>
        <option value="6" class="maxima">6pm</option>
        <option value="7" class="rivola">7pm</option>
        <option value="9" class="maxima">9pm</option>
</select>
```

You can simply hide and show them like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#cinema').on('change', function (ev) {
    $('#time option').hide();
    $("."+this.value).show();
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9v6ejvt/1/)

*Side note: unnecessary `DOM` manipulation is really bad...*

Comment: Awesome, this sounds like a great solution... I had originally tried using .hide() and .show(); as opposed to .remove() or .detach() but didn't have any luck (using chrome)... Will give this a go! Thanks for the response!

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what browser you're using T J?.. I can't seem to get any .hide()/.show() functions working on Chrome... This is very similar to what I had tried originally but have had to try to settle on .remove() or .detach() as I can't seem to get this working on Chrome!

Comment: Yeah I did, I can't get any of the fiddles working on Chrome on my local machine running Mac OSX... Might try pulling it up on the PC! Cheers, Zach.

Comment: PS - Thanks again for all your responses T J, all very much appreciated, apologies if I rubbed you the wrong way earlier!